# Why isnt java finding my json file? Ive checked spelling and everything

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I'm making a Minecraft mod for 1.12.2 and me and my friend are both getting stuck on a json file not being found.
Tut >>>>
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42z8_UDLmk4

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZDH2.png]

We have both been trying to figure this out for a while now and cant seem to find out why. He has done this exact thing before and it worked for him.

Comment: Sorry the image isnt showing one sec

Comment: Can you try with "assets" at the begin ?

Comment: Firstly, Eclipse is the recommended IDE for Forge Modding, and there's a bug with IntelliJ which is solved using the method  shown in the answer.

Comment: No, eclipse doesnt work for me, ive tried everything. Besides ive seen many people do this way ANNDDDD its easier to setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your build.gradle,

```
sourceSets {
    main { output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir }
}
```

Then, do `gradlew --refresh-dependencies`